# Remove Automatically Added CSS Styles from CKEditor

Tags: combobox, styles, ckeditor, config

My problem is that CK Editor is detecting and adding css classes from my main style sheet (in the parent page), which is causing the Styles combo to display unnecessary and undesirable styles in a very long list.

I want to remove the styles that are being automatically added to the stylescombo.

I want CK Editor to ONLY display the styles I define in the config and none of the default or parent styles.

I have tried various techniques from the docs and from S.O., but it does not seem to work.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {

// I thought this is how you use the stylescombo plugin but it does nothing
config.stylesSet = 'custom:/ckeditor/styles.js';
config.stylesCombo_stylesSet = 'custom:/ckeditor/styles.js';

//I want only this style to display in the Styles combo.
//This does get added, but with all the other junk styles I do not want. 
config.stylesSet = [
{ name: 'Bolder', element: 'span', attributes: { style: 'font-weight:bolder'} }
];

};
```

I am using CK Editor 4 and the stylescombo plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you mistakenly included `stylesheetparser` plugin in your build so this may help:

```
config.removePlugins = 'stylesheetparser';
```

Or you can build a new CKEditor package without this plugin.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I thought That parser was necessary for the stylescombo to work. Now I see that they are separate.